# How to make sample regular FaceTime call in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very beginner in iOS and present I am doing one project in that project I have to make simple video call facility for users (i.e regular Face-time call,Based on persons phone numbers I need to make video call),I have seen so many sample tutorials but no one explain how to make sample regular face video call

And for this I have searched lot in Internet but I did not get any result and I am eager to search and wait for this requirement, please someone post sample video calling app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am same stage Buddy as like you .I thing you can do or cover using `webrtc` or `quickblox` [webartc link](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios) and [quickblox link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios)   , i hope its helps you